# Deployment of custom SPI of keycloak in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak

I have custom SPI for keycloak 15 version and I want to deploy this every time automatically, means in fresh deployment or if the pod restarts.

I was able to do this using docker-compose but not getting anyway, how to do it in kubernetes ?

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  keycloak: 
    container_name: local_keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin            
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/vipul/Docker/common-keycloak-spi-0.1.jar
        target: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/common-keycloak-spi-0.1.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My approach might be: creating new docker image from jboss/keycloak which contains deployments all other necessary configurations.

Comment: Great, I tried that as well but docker file at this location doesn't work -> https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/dockerfile

Comment: Refer this [doc](https://faun.pub/keycloak-kubernetes-deployment-409d6ccd8a39) helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the experts, for providing trigger point. Was able to accomplish this using below docker file.

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
ADD common-keycloak-spi-0.1.jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env"]
CMD ["sh","/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```